# Maximum number of 'epsilon-bad' sets in a graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

We have a simple graph $G$ with maximum degree of $\Delta$. Let us call a set $A$ $\epsilon$-bad iff every vertex $u \in N(A)$ has at least $(1 - \epsilon) \Delta$ edges to $A$. (i.e. when a vertex $u$ is neighbor to at least one vertex in $A$ then almost all of its neighbors are in $A$)

How many $\epsilon$-bad sets can a graph $G$ have at most?

For example, we can set $G$ to be a collection of complete bipartite components $K_{(\Delta, \Delta)}$, then the number of $\epsilon$-bad sets is $\Omega(2^{\frac{n}{\Delta}})$ because we can set $A$ to include either no vertex from each component or all vertices from one side. Is there an example with more $\epsilon$-bad sets (e.g. $\Omega(2^{\delta n})$ for a $\delta > 0$)?

Comment: When you speak on the neighborhood of $A$, do you assume it is disjoint with $A$, or they may intersect?